# Ruby shell visibility

Tags: ruby, bash

I am trying to shell out in Ruby to use SSH. I know there is an SSH module but I don't want to use it. I find it clunky and confusing.

I am able to shell out and use SSH very nicely. I have one complaint, however, that I was hoping someone could offer some suggestions.

In Bash I can do this:

```
echo "PASSWORD" | ssh SERVER "sudo -S cat /etc/sudoers"
```

and it will show up as this when I do a ps -ef:

```
USER    8212  8837  0 09:31 pts/7    00:00:00 ssh SERVER sudo -S cat /etc/sudoers
```

The password is NOT shown when doing a ps -ef.

When I do the same in ruby, it is echoing the password:

```
%x[echo "#{password}" | ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes SERVER "sudo -S cat /etc/sudoers 2>/dev/null"].split("\n")
```

Shows up on the server with ps -ef:

```
sh -c echo "PASSWORD" | ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes SERVER "sudo -S cat /etc/sudoers 2>/dev/null"
```

Comment: I suspect you'd have to handle the piping manually.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Not really, but basically you want to redefine stdin for the second process. Googling around a bit should get you to an answer.

Comment: What OS are you on? On CentOS, ssh won't accept a password from a pipe, and that behavior has been seen on other versions of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ruby's [`Open3.popen3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) or [`Open3.capture3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3). But, I don't think it'll work because `ssh` doesn't accept the password from STDIN and will rewire the input to come from the keyboard, at least that's the behavior I've encountered on CentOS and Mac OS.

Here's some code to test it against:

```
require 'open3'

host = 'myhost'
user = 'myname'
password = 'mypassword'

stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(ENV, %Q[ssh #{host} "cat /home/#{user}/.bash_profile"])
pid = wait_thr[:pid]
stdin.puts password
stdin.close

puts stdout.read
stdout.close

puts stderr.read
stderr.close

exit_status = wait_thr.value
```

Running it shows the ssh prompt, even though the password is "puts" on the `stdin` channel, followed by the output once I enter the password:

```
myname@myhost's password: 
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
set editing-mode vi

# complete -W "$(echo $(grep '^ssh ' .bash_history | sort -u | sed 's/^ssh //'))" ssh
complete -W "$(echo $(grep '^ssh ' .bash_history | sort -u | sed 's/^ssh //' | sed 's/^.+@//'))" ssh

PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

While [Net::SSH](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/) might be "clunky", it is designed to allow you to cleanly work around this behavior in ssh. We use Net::SSH extensively internally, and it's working really well for our needs.